# Sprite does not change after new upload

Tags: css, ftp, css-sprites

In my personal website, I use sprites to show the contact icons (ie. skype, email, etc).

Recently I needed to add a new icon in the sprite therefore I have made a new one (sprite) and uploaded it to my FTP folder.

Everything works great on **localhost** but it does not work in my hosted website.

- [Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzWUL.png)
- [Hosted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHENr.png)

As you can see, **locahost** picture has got the LinkedIn icon, which I wanted to add, but on the hosted website it's not there.

- [Sprite Hosted Picture](http://giampaolofalqui.com/img/contacts-sprite.png)

CSS code:

```
.contact-aboutme, .contact-email, .contact-github, .contact-linkedin, .contact-skype, .contact-stackoverflow, .contact-twitter{
    background: url(../img/contacts-sprite.png) no-repeat;
}

.contact-aboutme{
    background-position: 0 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

.contact-email{
    background-position: -34px 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

.contact-github{
    background-position: -68px 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

.contact-linkedin{
    background-position: -136px 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

.contact-skype{
    background-position: -170px 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

.contact-stackoverflow{
    background-position: -102px 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

.contact-twitter{
    background-position: -204px 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

    # Don’t compress
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    #Dealing with proxy servers
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Where's what I tried to do:

1. Changing/deleting the file name - the image remained there.
2. Downloaded the file from the FTP to my computer just to make sure I didn't fail at uploading it - it was correct.
3. Deleted the browser cache - it didn't work.
4. Tried refreshing both with <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> - it didn't work.

I have no idea why this is happening.

I tried waiting as well like an hour or two, maybe it was a temporary issue but it didn't work.

Comment: It looks fine to me on http://giampaolofalqui.com/ ... Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: Not yet @yochannah - trying right now with Google Chrome.

Comment: It works on Google Chrome @yochannah which makes me think is a cache problem, but I have deleted it on Firefox!

Comment: FF is being a bit odd from the sounds of things, but I can't see that it's anything except a cache problem in all honesty, And given that it's working for others I think you should be fine :)

Comment: Alright. Thank you by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was browser issue with Firefox because it **works** with *Google Chrome*.

I thought about a cache problem immediatly when I saw it, even before trying Google Chrome, and I indeed deleted the cache of the browser, however the problem wasn't fixed.

There's really no other option except that **it's a Firefox issue**.